# How to generate WordPress feeds and where the feed is stored?

Tags: wordpress, rss

I just want to update the wordpress feed on `http://example.com/feed/`. The theme shows

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> RSS Feed" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
```

Then I updated the wp-include/feed-rss2.php file. But it had no effect. I just want to update the date format.

My quections are :
Which file is used to generate the feed in WordPress?
Where is the location stored the XML file?

Answer (score 0):

The feed in WordPress is actually not stored anywhere, but generated on the fly (dynamically) when a user agent hits the `/feed/` resource.

Side question: why would you want to update the date format? It turns out the RSS is a standard and that standard defines how dates should be displayed. WordPress actually outputs valid feeds by default. If you tamper with these, you'll probably end up breaking your feeds.

Comment: Thank you very much giving your idea to me.. I just ask about changing the date format.. my actual requrement is " I want to show the post thumbnail in the feed. I want to know which file on wordpress is used to genereate the feed.